# How do I hook into Channel closed event? Once per channel opened

Tags: spring, rabbitmq, amqp, spring-amqp

I have an annotation-based Rabbit consumer represented by a `@RabbitListener`-annotated method.

I also have a configuration class to configure my Factory e.g.

```
@Bean
public SimpleRabbitListenerContainerFactory rabbitListenerContainerFactory(
    ConnectionFactory connectionFactory) {
  var factory = new SimpleRabbitListenerContainerFactory();
  factory.setConnectionFactory(connectionFactory);
  ...
  return factory;
}
```

Sometimes my listener's code hits a PRECONDITION_FAILED error because it passes the broker's delivery acknowledgement timeout. **I want to run some handling code whenever this happens.**

I know that `channel.addShutdownListener()` exists but I don't know where to put it. I can't use the listener's method channel reference because that would add a listener for every message I process, which is not ideal.

I also understand that when a channel is closed, the listener will internally keep using the same ListenerContainer but with a new channel, so I will need to register the shutdown listener with the new channel in that case.

Basically, I need to add my handling code ONCE to each channel that is opened for my message listener.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

See `AbstractConnectionFactory.addChannelListener(ChannelListener)` configuration.

https://docs.spring.io/spring-amqp/docs/current/reference/html/#connection-channel-listeners

Comment: Seems the right path, but this would trigger the callback for all consumers. How do I limit the callback to only one specific endpoint?

Comment: Then you probably need a dedicated `ConnectionFactory` for that endpoint.

Comment: Thanks! This is exactly the solution I went for eventually. As for differentiating over consumers, could looking at the channel ID be a viable way? Can the same channel be used by two different endpoints?

Comment: Yes. It can. See a `CachingConnectionFactory`